# How to convert select to HTML with PHP tags inside of it

Tags: php, metabox, html, select

I apologize for asking such a simple question, but I am having a world of struggle in trying to convert the following echo statement to HTML with php tags inside of it.  I am trying to get my custom metabox to work correctly, but it will not save my data unless I use the following format as an echo string (very frustrating).

Thanks for any advice

```
echo '<p>
    <label>
    <select name="horizon_sort_listb" id="horizon_sort_listb">
    <option value="0" '
    .selected($horizon_featured,'normal',false)
    .'>Descending</option>
    <option value="special" '
    .selected($horizon_featured, 'special',false)
    .'>Ascending</option>
    </select><strong>Sort Order B</strong>'
    .'</label>
    </p>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Rule number #1 in programming, never ever be sorry for asking even the simplest question. If you want to use inline PHP tags, then @Rick's answer is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An example: your code

```
<option value="0" '
    .selected($horizon_featured,'normal',false)
    .'>Descending</option>
```

HTML code with some PHP mixed in:

```
<option value="0" <?php echo .selected($horizon_featured,'normal',false); ?>>Descending</option>
```

Basically, you just put a `<?php echo $something;?>` where you want the PHP stuff to be.

Answer (score 1):

There are the couple of ways to do this.

- [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)
- [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

A better and more efficient way is to use printf in your code like this:

```
printf( '<p>
            <label>
              <select name="horizon_sort_listb" id="horizon_sort_listb">
                <option value="0" %s>Descending</option>
                <option value="special" %s>Ascending</option>
              </select>
              <strong>Sort Order B</strong>
            </label>
          </p>',
          selected( $horizon_featured,'normal', false ),
          selected( $horizon_featured, 'special', false )
        );
```

And if want to save all formatting string into a variable then use sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that was consistant with the rest of my HTML formating within my child theme.  The following works just fine.

```
 <p>
            <label>
            <select name="horizon_sort_listb" id="horizon_sort_listb">
            <option value="desc" <?php echo selected($horizon_sort,'desc',false)?>>Descending</option>
            <option value="asc" <?php echo selected($horizon_sort,'asc',false)?>>Acsending</option>
            </select><strong>Sort Order B</strong>
            </label>
        </p>
```